# PHP session cookies in a subdomain using IE11/Safari

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, cookies, safari

I'm losing the session between redirects in both Internet Explorer 11 and Safari (works fine on Chrome, Opera and Firefox).

When I try to login using `www.subdomain.domain.com` the error occurs on IE/Safari, but even on them it works fine if I use the IP (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder`).

I'm trying to setup the session like:

```
session_name("somename");
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/folder/');
session_start();
```

I have already tried:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/folder/', '.domain.com);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/folder/', '.subdomain.domain.com);
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/folder/', 'domain.com);  <-- without the preceding dot
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/folder/', 'subdomain.domain.com);
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com"); <-- before set_cookie_params
```

But none of them seems to work.